# Loading Images into Gallery using PHP and JavaScript takes very long sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

A callback function triggers when my XMLHttpRequest has finished. I use an asynchronous JavaScript Function to load the content of a file that has been created by the PHP `file_put_contents()` function.

My problem is, that sometimes loading the gallery elements takes a very long time. I should rather return the html code I want to load as a string instead of writing it into a file.. but I do not know how?

This is my Javascript:

```
function xhr(php, form, after) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            after();
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', php, true);
    xhr.send(new FormData($(form)));
}
```

How can I get the corresponding PHP script to export a String? I would need something that puts `$myExportString` as parameter inside `after()` then I could use it like this:

```
xhr("../session/searchquery.php", "searchfilterterms", function( myExportString ) {         

    document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = myExportString;

});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't just returning the gallery data in the first AJAX call? Why are you making two? That aside, consider sending just the data to JavaScript and use that to build the HTML locally, rather than trying to send large amounts of HTML. You should also make sure you're caching appropriately.

Comment: There are not two AJAX calls just one an that's where I return the gallery data, sorry if this wasn't clear. Does building the HTML locally speed up the process significantly or is it just a smaller thing? I'd rather only do it if it is a major improvement because I'd need to make a lot of changes for this to work..

Comment: Why are you saving a file on the server? Just return the generated HTML string in the response to your XmlHttpRequest, and then write some Javascript to put that HTML into your page. Otherwise you're a) having the overhead of disk I/O, and b) you're having to make 2 requests to the server (one to generate the HTML, and another to retrieve the file it's been saved to). This is not efficient at all.

Comment: Obviously there will then be a further 27 requests to the server to load all of the individual images (unless you've base64-encoded them into the HTML, you didn't mention?), so that won't ever be instant. But you can certainly make the process of loading the HTML more efficient as I've mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. _"How can I get the corresponding PHP script to export a String?"_...well if you showed us the relevant PHP code which currently generates the  file, then we might stand some chance of telling you. If I had to _guess_, you may simply need to `echo` the HTML string, rather than sending it to file_put_contents or whatever.

Comment: The php just generates a string in the end, the entire php is basically just sql with prepared statements and all that stuff. I do not see how I can get the `$finalVariableWithHTMLString` back into the JavaScript code.. that's why I generated the file with  `file_put_contents` in the first place. I couldn't find out how to do it any other way..

Comment: If you echo it, then it becomes the contents of the response to the AJAX call. That's how you return a response to a HTTP request in PHP - you echo stuff to the output. You can then get it from `xhr.responseText` in the Javascript. So you'd be able to write `after(xhr.responseText);`. I'm guessing you haven't worked much with AJAX before?

Comment: I see, that's how this works! Thank you very much. I will try that out as soon as possible. And yes your are right, I've done only very little with AJAX before..

Comment: It worked! Is there any way I can have multiple separate response texts like `xhr.responeTest1`, `xhr.responeTest2`, `xhr.responeTest3` ect.. or do I have to use a delimiter to separate multiple variables?

Comment: Well what would the purpose be, in this case? I thought you were returning some HTML to put into your page? Are you wanting to return multiple different pieces of HTML to put into different areas of the page? Or do you maybe want to return some sort of other message or value alongside the HTML?

Comment: Normally if people want to return multiple pieces of data from an AJAX request, they use a JSON object as the data structure. So you could put your HTML snippets / other data items into different properties of a JSON object (or different indices of an array, if that's more suitable). Then the JavaScript receives the JSON, can easily parse it into variables and then use it.

Comment: Okay, I will do that in the future.. for now I think a delimiter works fine too, since its just one more information I need. But yea, the JSON Object is definitely what I was looking for! If you want you can put your comments into an answer, I will then accept and upvote your answer to this question and this matter would be resolved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem - see below. Glad this has helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to save a file on the server. You can just return the generated HTML string in the response to your XmlHttpRequest, and then write some Javascript to put that HTML into your page.

Otherwise a) you've got the overhead of disk I/O, and b) you're having to make 2 requests to the server (one to generate the HTML, and another to retrieve the file it's been saved to). This is not efficient at all.

In the PHP, instead of saving the generated HTML string to the disk, you can echo it, e.g. something like

```
echo $finalVariableWithHTMLString;
```

(I don't know your exact code as it's not shown in the question). If you echo it, then it becomes the contents of the response to the AJAX call. That's how you return a response to a HTTP request in PHP - you echo stuff to the output.

You can then get it from the `xhr.responseText` variable in the JavaScript. So you'd be able to write

```
after(xhr.responseText);
```

in your example, to pass the HTML to your `after()` function.